# C# Tabcontrol messed up my form

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I had a form made up with buttons, textboxes, and labels. Then I decided to see if I could use tab control because I wanted to add other buttons but I didn't want them to be on the same page. So I cut all my buttons and textboxes and labels and I paste the tabcontrol. Then I paste all of the buttons and stuff back on in tab1. So before I moved on to making buttons I decided to test run the program. I got a page that came up and said nullreferenceexeption was unhandled. When I tried clicking on one of my button, I saw that there was no code inside it and it went from

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

to

```
private void Button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Then the errors kept coming up. Now I just want to make my form the way it was before but even though I deleted the tabcontrol, when I click my buttons they still have the `_Click_1` thing. Please tell me how I can fix this. I am new to C# so try to explain it simply.

And if you can, tell me how I can add the tabcontrol thing without messing up my entire program.

Also is there a way I could like roll back changes for a day or 2 in visual studio ultimate? Please get back as soon as possible I'm ripping my hair out I can't lose the program I've been working on for 2 weeks.

Comment: Unless you are using some form of source control, you can't roll back changes on Visual Studio.

Comment: You the designer in the VS to drag and drop all your buttons, etc components over a tab control. Do not make the tab control dock fully. Also in the background code (InitializeComponent) you can remove what ever unnecessary event handling done for your widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix most of these problems, but it's going to take a bit of work.  For each button, open the properties tab and go to the events section, find the event `Click` and click once in the text field.  You should see a drop down arrow, click that arrow and look at the list.  Find the event you expect the button to fire and click on it *(Hint : it doesn't have `_1` at the end)*

[image]